# Is there a simple LLVM Pass that combine a consecutive pair of Store and Load of a constant?

Tags: optimization, llvm, llvm-ir

I wonder if there is any existing pass of LLVM `opt` tool that helps to combine consecutive Load and Store of a constant?

For example, here is my simple bitcode that first stores the constant 1 into two registers and then loads it immediately.

```
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i32*, align 8
  %5 = alloca i32*, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  store i32* %2, i32** %4, align 8
  store i32* %3, i32** %5, align 8
  store i32 1, i32* %2, align 4
  store i32 1, i32* %3, align 4
  %6 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %7 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  %8 = icmp eq i32 %6, %7
```

I hope to simplify the above code into something like below:

```
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i32*, align 8
  %5 = alloca i32*, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  store i32* %2, i32** %4, align 8
  store i32* %3, i32** %5, align 8
  %8 = icmp eq i32 1, 1
```

Here, I cannot use the pass `-mem2reg` since the registers %2, %3, %4, %5 can't be eliminated due to the 2nd and the 3rd store. I also tried the pass `-instcombine` but it does many other simplification strategies that I don't want to use.

Does anyone know if there is an existing pass that can just simply combines and eliminates consecutive Load and Store of Constants?

Thank you for spending your time reading my question.

Comment: Does https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#mem2reg-promote-memory-to-register do what you want?

Comment: Hi, the `-mem2reg` cannot be used to eliminate `%2`, `%3` since these registers are also used in 2 instructions: `store i32* %2, i32** %4, align 8`  and `store i32* %3, i32** %5, align 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [`-gvn`](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#gvn-global-value-numbering) what you are looking for?

`-gvn`: Global Value Numbering
This pass performs global value numbering to eliminate fully and partially redundant instructions. *It also performs redundant load elimination*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Redundant load elimination is exactly what I am looking for. Although `-gvn` seems to do more optimization than I expect, but this is a very good clue for me to investigate further.